# Using redux toolkit and trying to update the state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I been at this for hours..
I'm fairly new to redux and redux toolkit

I currently have a signup form and when I try to sign up, it updates my backend which is using mongoDB, however it does not update my state in redux which I can't figure out.

**appApi.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const appApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'appApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8001' }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    signup: builder.mutation({
      query: user => ({
        url: '/users/signup',
        method: 'POST',
        body: user,
      }),
    }),

    login: builder.mutation({
      query: user => ({
        url: '/users/login',
        method: 'post',
        body: user,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useSignupMutation, useLoginMutation } = appApi;

export default appApi;
```

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import appApi from '../services/appApi';

const initialState = null;

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      appApi.endpoints.signup.matchFulfilled,
      (_, { payload }) => {
        console.log(_); // null why?
        console.log(payload); //null why?
        return payload;
      }
    );
    builder.addMatcher(
      appApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (_, { payload }) => payload
    );
  },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**EDIT SOLVED**

I figured it out, my frontend was correct, it was my backend that was wrong.

This was inside my users model file.

I forgot to add () at end of user.toObject;

**what I had before**

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;
  const userObject = user.toObject; <----- this was the problem
  delete userObject.password;

  return userObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    builder.addMatcher(
      appApi.endpoints.signup.matchFulfilled,
      (_, { payload }) => {
        console.log(_); // null why?
        console.log(payload); //null why?
        return payload;
      }
```

In this code, `_` is `state` - above that you declared `initialState` to be `null` - so that explains that `null`.

As for the payload, that is interesting but honestly I also don't quite believe that that's `null` unless the server would explicitly return that. Maybe take a look at the full action to see what's going on.

```js
    builder.addMatcher(
      appApi.endpoints.signup.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        console.log({state, action});
        return action.payload;
      }
```

Comment: What exactly should I look for in 'action'? I console.logged it and payload is still null.

Comment: Well, confirming that there is a valid action at first. If `action.payload` is `null` at that point, either you are not returning data from the server or you maybe have a CORS problem. Do you see any CORS error messages in your console?

Comment: I figured it out!. I edited my post. so it was wasn't my front end that was the problem, it was a problem in my backend for User model file. Thank you though!